# Sinatra Json Post Altered by Datamapper Save

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra, datamapper

I have a Sinatra app with this route that is requested by an Android app and returns some Json with connection information.

```
post '/getConnection' do
content_type :json

#session and tokens
session_id = 123 
agent_token = 456 
user_token = 789

#Create new room based on session and store
newRoom = Room.new
newRoom.attributes = {:sessionID => session_id,
  :agentToken => agent_token,
  :userToken => user_token}
newRoom.save

#Json
{:con =>[:session =>session_id,:token =>user_token]}.to_json
end
```

Everything works properly without the new room creation and database store(Using Datamapper by the way). However when I add it, or even a function that contains the code is messes up the response.

Here is the Room model:

```
class Room
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :sessionID, String
  property :agentToken, String
  property :userToken, String

end

DataMapper.finalize

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

Is there a way to implement a callback function or something that will return the Json and store the information without messing up the Json being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

The problem was with DataMapper not being required and configured in my app.rb file. I ended up with:

```
require 'data_mapper'
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://database-uri')

post '/getConnection' do
content_type :json

#session and tokens
session_id = 123 
agent_token = 456 
user_token = 789

#Create new room based on session and store
Room.create(
  :sessionID      => session_id,
  :agentToken       => agent_token,
  :userToken => user_token
)

#Json
{:con =>[:session =>session_id,:token =>user_token]}.to_json
end
```